# display last four number on the array

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop

Suppose that you write a JavaScript program that asks for someone's phone number. The phone number will be provided in the format of "XXX-XXX-XXXX". You need to pull out the last four digits and use an alert function to display it to the screen in a pop-up. The variable containing the phone number that you need to evaluate will be named "phone_number". For example, if this phone number is provided, your program should alert "1111".

var phone_number = "568-654-1111";

Comment: Please add a code snippet with the best attempt you have so far. It is unlikely that someone can help you without seeing what needs to be done. Also your question right now seems to be a very basic bit of knowledge and most users think that those questions do not belong on StackOverflow and the user needs to show some own research efforts, which is not evident here. You named a few keywords that can help you: "array javascript substring" or "javascript alert" or "javascript stub" "how to tutorial hello world" (if you did basic research already, please update your question accordingly).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
const lastDigits = phone_number.split('-')[2];
```

Step-by-step:

```js
let phone_number = '568-654-1111';
const array = phone_number.split('-'); // ['568','654','1111']
const lastDigits = array[2];
```